# How to ignore where clause if condition is empty in Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I know this same question is already asked before. But I have tried the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46438705/6854117) but it's not working for me.

```
 $comp_ids = AllowArea::find()
    ->select(['comp_code'])
    ->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id])
    ->column();

    $ref = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select([
            'ProductCode',
            'ProductNameFull',
            'ProductSpec',
            'ProductGroup',
            'CompanyCode',
            'CompanyName'
            ,'Price',
            'PurchasePrice'
        ])->from('Product')
        ->andFilterWhere(['CompanyCode' =>  $comp_ids])
        ->all(Yii::$app->sds);
```

It's giving me empty data.

**Flow**
The users are assigned areas and some users are assigned areas with a company. So I want the above query to return me the result whether the condition fails or not.

**Update 1**
The `SQL` which I am getting is

```
SELECT `ProductCode`, `ProductNameFull`, `ProductSpec`, `ProductGroup`, 
`CompanyCode`, `CompanyName`,
`Price`, `PurchasePrice` FROM `Product` WHERE `CompanyCode` IS NULL
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the generated sql query?

Comment: with `or` the raw sql query is `SELECT ProductCode, ProductNameFull, ProductSpec, ProductGroup, CompanyCode, CompanyName,
Price, PurchasePrice FROM Product WHERE CompanyCode IS NULL`

Comment: Your code should work, can you post the rawSql generated?

Comment: @Paul I have updated my question and added a flow. You can check it.

Comment: You are getting the desired data without the condition? You can use alternate way to `andFilterWhere()` by splitting query into two parts. `if (!empty($comp_ids)) {$ref = $ref ->where(['CompanyCode' =>  $comp_ids]); }.. $ref = $ref->all(Yii::$app->sds);`

Comment: Try to add other where conditions, and see if the result SQL is the same.

Comment: @InsaneSkull This solution is also not working for me. As the `$comp_ids` is not empty. It also count the column so it's never empty

Comment: Since `comp_code` column in first query can be `NULL` what about applying `array_filter` on `$comp_ids` or adding `andWhere('comp_code IS NOT NULL')` to the first query?

Comment: I do with @MichalHynčica. This is because `AllowArea` has a lot of records with specific `user_id`, whereas their `comp_code` is `NULL`. You should filter this kind of record by adding `andWhere('comp_code IS NOT NULL')`, just as Michal pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing works, from what you were told, then you can try:

```
$ref = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select([
        'ProductCode',
        'ProductNameFull',
        'ProductSpec',
        'ProductGroup',
        'CompanyCode',
        'CompanyName'
        ,'Price',
        'PurchasePrice'
    ])->from('Product');

if (!empty($comp_ids)) {
    $ref->andFilterWhere(['CompanyCode' => $comp_ids]);
}

$ref = $ref->all(Yii::$app->sds);
```

Comment: This solution is also not working for me. As the `$comp_ids` is not empty. It also count the column so it's never empty

Comment: `count($comp_ids)` gives me `int(40)`

Comment: `var_dump($comp)` gives me `array(40) {
[0]=>
NULL
[1]=>
NULL
[2]=>
NULL
[3]=>
NULL
[4]=>
NULL
[5]=>
NULL
[6]=>
NULL
[7]=>
NULL
[8]=>
NULL
[9]=>
NULL
[10]=>
NULL
[11]=>
NULL
[12]=>
NULL
[13]=>
NULL
[14]=>
NULL
[15]=>
NULL
[16]=>
NULL
[17]=>
NULL
[18]=>
NULL
[19]=>
NULL
[20]=>
NULL
[21]=>
NULL
[22]=>
NULL
[23]=>
NULL
[24]=>
NULL
[25]=>
NULL
[26]=>
NULL
[27]=>
NULL
[28]=>
NULL
[29]=>
NULL
[30]=>
NULL
[31]=>
NULL
[32]=>
NULL
[33]=>
NULL
[34]=>
NULL
[35]=>
NULL
[36]=>
NULL
[37]=>
NULL
[38]=>
NULL
[39]=>
NULL
}`

Comment: It's hard to say how to do it right when you can't see everything.

Based on the situation, you can try this:

`if (array_sum($comp_ids) != 0 ) {
     $ref->andFilterWhere(['CompanyCode' => $comp_ids]);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try user `orFilterWhere()` this Adds an additional WHERE condition to the existing one but ignores empty operands.
The new condition and the existing one will be joined using the 'OR' operator.
This method is similar to orWhere(). The main difference is that this method will remove empty query operands. As a result, this method is best suited for building query conditions based on filter values entered by users.

Comment: not working either

Comment: @Moeez Not working in what way, can you explain? Is there any error response or something else?

Comment: No there is no error. I am using it in my `REST API`. And with `or` and `and` i am getting empty response.

Comment: with `or` the raw sql query is `SELECT ProductCode, ProductNameFull, ProductSpec, ProductGroup, CompanyCode, CompanyName,
Price, PurchasePrice FROM Product WHERE CompanyCode IS NULL`

Comment: I want to return the data on whether the where conditions fail or not

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to add `Is Not Null` condition to the first query

```
 $comp_ids = AllowArea::find()
    ->select(['comp_code'])
    ->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->id])
    ->andWhere('`comp_code` IS NOT NULL' )  
    ->column();
```

And change andFilterWhere in the second query on

```
->andWhere('`CompanyCode` IN (' . join(',',  $comp_ids) . ')'))
```